# Android Application - Getting points of interest from a certain location using Google Places API for Android

Tags: android, api, google-places-api

I'm coding an Android application and I'm trying to get and display a list of touristic attractions from a certain city using Google Places API for Android (i.e. Central Park, Times Square...). However I've been checking the docs from here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup and I haven't found anything similar for Android.

On the other hand, the Google API for web services: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro does have that functionality I'm looking for but Google says strictly not to use this API in an Android app.

I wanted to know if is possible to use this web services API in an Android app, and what other alternatives are there for such functionality I want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this google places API url. You will get the point of interest/Attraction/Tourists places in (For Eg:) **New York City**. You have to use the **CITY NAME** with the keyword **Point Of Interest**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=new+york+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=API_KEY
```

These result have all the details of a place like categorization (Museum, Landmark, ...) a picture, a two - three line summary about it and rating.

[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867833/3623027)